# Aloha Editor disable image crop

Tags: javascript, css, aloha-editor

How to disable the crop button in toolbar for image plugin other way than vis css? The config doesn't work.

```
Aloha.settings = {
    plugins: {
       image: {
              'maxWidth': 600,
              'minWidth': 3,
              'maxHeight': 200,
              'minHeight': 3,
              ui: {
                 oneTab      : false, //Place all ui components within one tab
                 insert      : true,
                 reset       : true,
                 aspectRatioToggle: true, // Toggle button for the aspect ratio
                 align       : true, // Menu elements to show/hide in menu
                 resize      : true, // Resize buttons
                 meta        : true,
                 margin      : false,
                 crop        : false,
                 resizable   : true, // Resizable ui-drag image
                 handles     : 'ne, se, sw, nw'
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find ID or classname of this element by inspect element on browser, and force hide it or diable by javascript code or css

Comment: @TaronPro I know that, but it looks like very poor solution. Any other ideas, why this config doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin, but I know that even very complex plugins can patch by javascript or css

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so still don't know why the config is not working and disabling **crop button** via css requires a lots of changes in the code (all buttons need to be positioned again) but in **aloha.js** (the main script file) find variable `var defaultToolbarSettings` and under image settings remove `"imageCropButton"` from `components`.

That way the **crop button** won't be rendered in DOM.